# CSS triangular border over of the image

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I need crossbrowser solution of triangle div border over image. Maybe i should use "canvas" or something else. Main div must have auto height and image always on fixed position.

[Final result](http://s14.postimg.org/4pf9cbtup/tri.png)

```css
.border {
    width: 600px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.border_image{
    float: right;
    background: url("http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/35/images/circle/Macaw_circle_image_(c)_Zig_Kock_WWF.jpg?1345562675") no-repeat;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    position: absolute;
    right:-20px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
    <div class="border_image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that may be difficult with just css. In your case I would create an image to cover the right part of your container. I have made this with css: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/p2xfu6ky/1/)** but It is not a perfect solution as I can't seem to perfectly join the diferent parts I have used. And zooming in and out will mess it slightly. Anyway I had some fun making it even if this answer may not be valid:

css:

```
.right {
    height: calc(100% - 24px);
    border-left:3px solid blue;
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-40px;
    top:24px;
    background-color:white;
}
.right:before {
    content:' ';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-5.5px;
    left:0px;
    transform: rotate(45deg); 
    border-left:3px solid blue;
    background-color:white;
}
.right:after {
    content:' ';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-39px;
    left:0px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg); 
    border-left:3px solid blue;
    background-color:white;
}
```